# Editing Array of Struct in another Function

Tags: c, arrays, struct

As I may or may not have stated in a previous question, I am a newbie to C Programming and only have experience previously with Java, so I am fairly incompetent at using Structs and Pointers and may not have grasped these concepts well on the first time.

So I was playing with C and when I tried out the following program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define buf_sz 32

struct friends {
    char name[buf_sz];
    int number;
};
typedef struct friends friend;

void addfriend (friend * friendArr, int index);
void removefriend (friend * friendArr);

void main () {

    int index;
    int troll;

    friend friendArr[50];

    printf("1. Add Friend Name, 2. Remove Friend. Other buttons. Do nothing\n");
    scanf(" %d", &troll);

    while ((troll == 1) && (troll == 2)) {
        switch (troll) {
            case 1: addfriend(friendArr, index);
                index++;
                break;
            case 2: removefriend(friendArr);
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (friendArr[i].name != NULL) {
            printf("%s\t%d\n", friendArr[i].name, friendArr[i].number);
        }
    }

}

void addfriend (friend * friendArr, int index) {

    char buf[buf_sz];
    int number;

    printf("Add a friend's name\n");
    fgets(buf, buf_sz-1, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, " %s", friendArr[index].name);

    printf("Add his number\n");

    scanf(" %d", &number);
    friendArr[index].number = number;

}

void removefriend (friend * friendArr) {

    char buf[buf_sz];
    char name[buf_sz];
    int check;

    printf("Add a friend's name you wanna remove\n");

    fgets(buf, buf_sz-1, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, " %s", name);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (friendArr[i].name == name) {
            strcpy(friendArr[i].name, "");
        }
    }

}
```

My Output was given as:

```
1. Add Friend Name, 2. Remove Friend. Other buttons. Do nothing
1
@R      2009984
        0
        624
        4
 v      144
        0
l�      685382481
        32767
��G�    364104144
       0
0�G�    368262747
       32517
@�G�    440903072
�       32517
        368167105
       32517
�G�     370332944
       32517
_�g     370428400
       32517
        368167105
       32517
        364032000
       0
        0
        32517
�I      368217097
       0
��G�    368166640
       32517
���     370428400
       0
'       0
        0
pQ      368182487
       32517
        370431760
       0
���     0
        0
8W      0
        32767
W       440904224
�       32517
���     370432664
       0
        0
        32517
��G�    368232864
       32767
```

Which is basically a bunch of strange numbers, which I do not get the meaning of.

The desired output would be a message to print the question add a user's name and number if 1 was pressed, and delete a user if 2 was pressed, then print all the users.

I believe the problem here is my passing of array to struct, but I am not sure.

I have searched Stack Overflow everywhere for possible places I have went wrong, but I could not find anything that helped.

Can you friendly people point out where I went wrong?

Comment: You never initialize `index`, so `index++;` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: You cannot compare strings with `==` in C. The best thing you can do at this point is to 1) turn on all warnings in your compiler and set them to be treated as errors, and 2) learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: `(troll == 1) && (troll == 2)` can never be true. How can a variable be equal to two different numbers at the same time? I think you meant `||`.

Comment: I believe that I summarised index as an int. Are you talking about the index in the main function?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)` is printing more friends than have actually been added.

Comment: You declared the variable, but never gave it an initial value.

Comment: Change that to `int index = 0;`

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I will retry my program. @Barmar I understand what you mean now. Thank you very much.

Comment: that for loop should then be `for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)`

Comment: And you can't compare strings using `==` in `if (friendArr[i].name == name) {`. Use `if (strcmp(friendArr[i].name, name) == 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your variables:

```
void main () {

    int index = 0;    // <<-- THIS 
    int troll;

    // Make some friends
    friend friendArr[50];

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
        friendArr[i].name[0] = '\0';   // <<-- AND THE NAME
```

When you print out the friends list, the members names cannot be compared to `NULL`, since they are not pointers.  (well they can be compared, but it does not make sense).  It would be better, once the data-set is initialised to blank, to check to see if there's a name set.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{
    if (friendArr[i].name[0] != '\0') 
    {
        printf("%s\t%d\n", friendArr[i].name, friendArr[i].number);
    }
}
```

Also as @Groo points out, it's not valid to compare C strings with `==`.  Use `strcmp()` instead.  Here we test that `strcmp()` returns `0` when the strings are identical.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{
    if (strcmp(friendArr[i].name, name) == 0) 
    {
        strcpy(friendArr[i].name, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.